# vim/terminal highlighting conditionals

Tags: vim, terminal, syntax-highlighting

I am just trying to set up vim such that I get the colors I prefer.

I created a `~.vimrc file` and set `syntax on`

I then went `Terminal > Preferences > Profile > Text` and have been changing the ANSI colors such that the file looks the way I want

Unfortunately I have come across the problem that conditionals (if, else, and so on) are not using any of the ANSI colors and I therefore cannot change my preferences this way.

I have been looking in the vim syntax located at `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax` to see how this is implemented. I see where these are grouped, but cannot seem to find where the colors are assigned and why I cannot overwrite just this in my preferences.

**where am I able to go to find this code, and what are some of the options for customizing this**

#### NOTE

- I am on Mac Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: You shouldn't be changing those files (I guess), are you aware that you can choose your colorscheme ? See `:help colorscheme` from inside vim

Comment: I am trying to customize a colorscheme. I know I can write a colorscheme, but I didn't really want to do that so I was curious if there is a way to change the default of the conditionals to be an ANSI color so I can customize it and where these defaults are so I can change them

Answer (score 0):

There are many colorscheme available. My favourite colorscheme to highlight the keywords is gruvbox following are the steps to install.

## installing pathogen

`mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim`

## installing the colorscheme gruvbox

`git clone https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox.git ~/.vim/bundle/gruvbox`

## add the following to your ~/.vimrc file

`execute pathogen#infect()`

`colorscheme gruvbox
set background=dark    " Setting dark mode`